# How do you find the rate of heat flow through a multilayered wall?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's say that there is a wall, one side 20 C, the other 0 C. In between, there are 3 layers. One of copper, iron, and steel (hypothetical). The wall would look like this:
20 - Copper - Iron - Steel - 0. According to the video I watched, the heat transfer rate would be A(20)/(L/k), where in this case, L/k would be the sum of L/k for each layer of the wall, or the resistance for each layer. I don't understand where this solution comes from, or how to derive it from Fourier's equation. Can anyone explain how to come to this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to equalize heat flow in every layer and this equation will result as summing the thermal resistance, as already said @trula

Answer (score 1):

In Fourrier law you have conductance and Resistance. I suppose your L/k  ist the resistance? than Resistances jaust ad up; see wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction